# Abstract Algebra- Cosets in $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

We know that $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ is a group. Let $2\mathbb{Z}^{2} = \lbrace (2a,2b):a,b \in\mathbb{Z} \rbrace$. $2\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ is the set of vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ with both coordinates even. What are the four cosets of $2\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ in $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$?

Comment: DRH  For your own self-interest, it's not a good idea to accept an answer when the answerer asks you to do so merely 6 minutes after your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$1-(2n+1,2n+1)$$
$$2-(2n,2n+1)$$
$$3-(2n,2n)$$
$$4-(2n+1,2n)$$

I hope you get the idea. It is about odd and even coordinates of $Z^{2}$